# Как пустить трафик одного приложение отдельным потоком

Tags: linux, debian, администрирование, kali-linux, трафик

У меня openvpn весь трафик гонит по туннелю, мне нужно что бы transmission качал не через vpn как это сделать?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210982/110559